# Kotlin : ArrayAdapter with JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, adapter

how can I send a json array through my adapter ?

I need to show some data from my json : (show in first "name", then "sub1" which contains data1.X.X and at last data2.X.X). for now, I only show the "name" of the item.

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "array": {
      "sub1": [
        [
          "data1.1.0",
          "data1.1.1",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "data1.2.0",
          "data1.2.1",
          "1"
        ]
      ],
      "sub2": [
        [
          "data2.1.0",
          "data2.1.1",
          "1"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is my adapter :

```
class ListAdapterScolaire (context: Context, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<String>, private val arguments: Bundle?, private val forScol : Boolean) : MatchableArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list) {

private val TAG = ListAdapterScolaire::class.java.simpleName


override fun onBind(item: String?, itemView: View?, position: Int) {
    super.onBind(item, itemView, position)
    if(itemView != null){
        val arret = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.arret)
        arret?.text = "name"
        val aller = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aller)
        aller.text = "data1.1" + "data1.2"
        val retour= itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.retour)
        retour.text = "data2.1" + "data2.2"
    }
}
```

My adapter is extending this [class](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0). It allows me to add multiple level of code for my layout. By "multiple level", I mean that I can use for example LinearLayout where usually there's only a simple TextView

See my listView layout (it's an xml file that will be used to display each of my json content) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arret"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        tools:text="Nom arret"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
                android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
                android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                tools:text="Aller"
                android:id="@+id/aller"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/retour"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
                    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
                    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    tools:text="Retour"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT :

Pojos

```
    class myobject {

    var array: array? = null

    var name: String? = null
    }
```

And

```
class array {
    var dataFirst: Array<Array<String>>? = null

    var dataSecond: Array<Array<String>>? = null
}
```

Comment: can you add pojo ? i have code for you but dont know your pojo

Comment: You'd better to convert first your JSON data to POJO. Then, you will be able to give to your adapter the 'real' objects you want to display

Comment: What is POJO ? I've seen that it's the most basic object

Comment: Its dataclass file for make object of array

Comment: It's for making an object so ?

Comment: Your Pojo class will look like :  'class UserProfile(var username: String)'

Comment: See updated answer. What's next